# Modifying attributes in a QGIS model

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I want to make a model where from a vector layer of points, with a numeric field, a buffer at constant distance is created. Then that buffer will have a field with the value of the distance, which is created after making the buffer. What I want is to multiply the field that was in the point layer by the new field in the buffer. The input values ​​are the vector layer and the numeric field, but I can't get that field to multiply with the new field created in the buffer.

Comment: When you say "I can't get that field to multiply with the new field created in the buffer", perhaps you can expand your question by explaining what methods you have tried? Also, perhaps some screenshots or examples, as it's not really clear what you are aiming to achieve.